# How to request iOS permissions (camera and location) on runtime?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm making an application in Unity which uses the phone's camera and the user's location. I want these permission popups to be shown to the user, after they've read why I want them to give permission. So pressing the "Accept" button in the app should check if the app has a certain permission and if not: ask that permission.
So in short, what I need is:
- A way to check if the app has a specific permission
- A way to trigger the permission popup
- (Nice to have:) A way to check if permission was granted or denied in said popup

I've already built exactly this for Android, as android provides ways to do so. 
After googling, I've found that iOS will prompt permissionpopups when the app starts a certain service that requires an ungranted permission. This means I could simply start up the location service or camera to check if the app has these permissions. I think this is a dirty fix, though, as it requires the app to start services that are not needed at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can use this library: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

If you want to retrieve the location permission, you can use this code:

```
try
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if(await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
        //Best practice to always check that the key exists
        if(results.ContainsKey(Permission.Location))
            status = results[Permission.Location];
    }

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        var results = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(10000);
        LabelGeolocation.Text = "Lat: " + results.Latitude + " Long: " + results.Longitude;
    }
    else if(status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    LabelGeolocation.Text = "Error: " + ex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The plugin is probably a bit much for what I need, as I only need two iOS permissions. I also noticed that calender permission is always asked? I don't think I should have that in my app.

Comment: You won't have the need  to ask for calendar permission but you only need it inside your info.plist please upvote and mark as answers if it helped you!

Comment: Oh, that's good news! Although I am not quite sure how to use this plugin in my Unity project. The github page doesn't say anything about Unity and I can't find examples of other people implementing it in their Unity projects.